# About Kotlin and functions

Tags: kotlin

So Ive started learning Kotlin and I have a question about functions.

In Kotlin you can do the javascript thing of creating a variable that can hold any type. But functions need to have their parameters typed.

So is the practice in Kotlin to type all variables anyway? 
Is it not kind of pointless allowing the variables to be untyped but forcing types for the parameters and return values of functions?

Comment: Do you mean `dynamic`? What's stopping you from using that as a parameter or return type?

Comment: Im not sure what dynamic is. Im just watching videos to learn and he went over basic functions. The parameters have to have something like fun speak(line: String). So you have to type the parameter, but the variables created in the program do not have to be strictly typed

Comment: Typing of variables is redunant code, like type param in generic initialization, you just print `new HashMap<>()`, and not `new HashMap<String>()`

Comment: What do you mean by "the javascript thing of creating a variable that can hold any type" then? Please [edit] the question to include a Kotlin example so it's clear what you're referencing. And Kotlin doesn't allow variables to be statically untyped. Even `dynamic` is a static type, just a special one.

Comment: yeah but its safer to type the variables. No one can come along and put an int into whats meant to be a String variable. I understand the benefits, I love it in javascript. But then javascript doesnt expect parameters to be typed.

Comment: @chris when you do var x in javascript you just create a variable that has no type. As opposed to something like int x in java where it is only an integer variable. In Kotlin you can do var x as well and create it without a type. But you can also do var x:int

Comment: You can't create variables without a type in Kotlin. Doing `var x` produces the compiler error *This variable must either have a type annotation or be initialized*. Doing `var x = 5` means `x` is an `Int` and won't let you change its type. For example, `x = "abc"` produces an error.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the vid. When I saw it creating the var with no type I thought it could be reassigned like javascript. Watching on my phone, cos it was just the basics, so no way to test myself. Cheers for clearing it up

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
val x = "Pizza"
```

kotlin infers from the declaration that 'x' is a string, there isn't some magic going on, if you try

```
var x = "Pizza"
x = 42
```

it won't work, because x is of a type String.

kotlin translates to java, and java is a "Statically typed language", which means the type of a field have to be known at runtime,
other languages, like Javascript are a "Dynamically typed languages", which in them the variables types doesn't have to be known at runtime, so it can make the developer life a bit easier ( or harder ).